# Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to build an app with openCV and Firebase ML Kit. But I get the following error while building project:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzv found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

I have tried searching exact same error and didn't get anything, then I searched duplicate class issues, there wasn't a certain way of solving the problem, everyone shared their experience and neither of them worked for me.

This is my **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cameraactivity"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
    implementation project(path: ':sdk')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

It's all about this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
```

When I comment this line, it doesn't give errors when I build project (I haven't added functionality yet).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add the following in build.gradle:Module

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.1'
```

And in build.gradle:Project

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

In buildscript-->dependencies.

Comment: it worked for me, used updated version of each dependancies

Comment: This solution not worked on me, but adding Firebase Bom worked

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue with the 24.1.0 version of firebase-ml-vision.
Here is the official resolution solution :

[Firebase Release Note MLKIT Self Serve Fixes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#mlkit-self-serve-fixes)

So I had to add a dependency to play-services-vision that I did not need anymore before :

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1'

I hope that they will fix it in the next versions

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively and preferably, you should move to the new ML Kit SDK which we launched early June. The on-device APIs are considered deprecated in Firebase ML and updates / improvements are only available in the new SDK. To help with the switch, migration guides can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration).

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your answer. I have already done that.

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue,if you are using firebase dependencies update following to latest version in app/build.gradle  see attached process

```
dependencies {
 
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
}
```

Get the latest version via the documentation
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 2):

We were facing a similar issue. I am going to add some steps here based on which hopefully someone else who faces this issue can later sort it out themselves.
Our issue was,

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkStagingReleaseDuplicateClasses'. 
> 1 exception was raised by workers: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbl found in modules play-services-vision-common-19.1.3-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.3) and play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0)
```

We tried a lot of things, including steps mentioned here in these set of answers, but nothing worked. After a lot of brute forcing, and mind bending decryption of errors, we did this.

The error was simple, something was showing up in 2 places. Both places were not implemented anywhere in our `build.gradle`. So it was obviously coming from the group in which the module is placed, in our case `com.google.android.gms`. So, first we checked what's the version we have implemented for gms, only to realise nothing wrong there. Though we did play around a bit by upgrading and downgrading it, nothing really happened.

So we thought, why not just check where else in the app are one of the duplicates being implemented, only to realise, we have installed react-native-camera, which uses play-services-vision and has it implemented in it's own `build.gradle`. So now, a bulb went off in our head, we have implemented react-native-camera in our own build.gradle too. Like so
`implementation project(':react-native-camera')`. Why not make it stop trying to implement play-services-vision-face-contour-internal from our end?

Thus coming to the solution like so,

```
implementation (project(':react-native-camera')) {
  exclude module: 'play-services-vision-face-contour-internal'
}
```

By doing this, the duplicate error stopped showing and we could continue with our development in peace.

I know there's not a lot of technical knowledge here, this is here just so someone could also look into something like this when they face something like this. I don't know if that made sense

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by defining the dependencies of `gms` custom version

```
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0")
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1") <--
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision- 
common:19.1.1")<--
```